# Wordpress Page Template Showing index.php instead of selected template

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have been looking into this issue for about 3 hours straight now and I am stumped. I had a custom theme working for months now. Just as I am about to pass it over to my friend I double check the site and notice all the pages are not showing properly. When I click on the pages they all have the proper theme selected in the CMS but they are ALL displaying the index.php page instead of their selected theme.

When you click **links**, **how it works**, etc...those are all suppose to be different pages with different themes. It is weird because it was working before and I don't recall making any changes that would have upset the system.

Also I am using the ACF plugin. I doubt this is an issue because the Custom Fields are indeed showing in the CMS but like I said, on the front end it is clearly pulling the index.php page. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Thanks in Advance!**

Answer (score 6):

Problem Fixed! I just updated the permalinks. P.S. there is no button that says update permalinks. You just have to login to the wordpress CMS > Click Settings > Click Permalinks > Click "Save Changes" to update permalinks.

Comment: Had a very similar problem - create a new page template, but the new permalink shows only the main page, and not the template contents. Updating permalinks didn't work. Went back to edit the page, changed the permalink from the default `.../edit-account/` to `.../edit/`, and everything works. Completely reversible - working/not working - when changing the permalink. Definitely something flakey here - WP4.1.1.

Comment: Same issue. just made some changes and it started using index.php instead of custom template. reverted after simply click save on permalinks page... super dumb

Answer (score 0):

You should check the files present in you theme directory. If you have a look at the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/File%3aTemplate_Hierarchy.png) from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), you will notice that Wordpress looks for specific files. If none of the files are found, it is `index.php` which is loaded.

Have you tried to switch themes and see if other themes are working fine?

Comment: Yes, when I try another theme the same thing happens. I click the corresponding page and it only loads the index.php page.  I selected One, column no sidebar as the page template for contact us page and it shows with the blog posts and sidebar still.

Comment: Try to backup your database, files export your posts. Then set wordpress up on your localhost and see if the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the exact url in website url box in Settings > General  and check

- WordPress Address (URL)
- Site Address (URL)

and the template should be insite that wordpress installation directory and specifically named.